# How to get the original curl request from pycurl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests, pycurl

Is there any way if i use,

```
 crl = pycurl.Curl()
 crl.setopt(pycurl.URL, "www.google.com")
```

i need to print the original curl request for troubleshooting

```
curl www.google.com
```

Comment: pycurl doesn't use the command line tool at all, it uses libcurl.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in pycurl that composes curl commands.

Note also that there are many things you can do with pycurl that cannot be represented with curl command (for example, writing to a Python IO object).

Answer (score 0):

You could use subprocess to get the output:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["curl","www.google.com"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print(stdout.decode().strip() , stderr.decode().strip())
```